# On the differentiable manifold definition given by Serge Lang

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

There are some questions about Lang's definition of differentiable manifold, but I think they does not ask the same (I think everybody think that).

My definition is taken from *Fundamentals of differential geometry*, Springer (1999). The definition is the following:

> > Let $X$ be a set. An **atlas of class** $C^p$ ($p\geq0$) on $X$ is a collection of pairs $(U_i,\varphi_i)$ ($i$ ranging in some index set), satisfying the following conditions:
> >
> > **AT 1.** Each $U_i$ is a subset of $X$ and the $U_i$ cover $X$.
> >
> > **AT 2.** Each $\varphi_i$ is a bijection of $U_i$ onto an open subset $\varphi_iU_i$ of some Banach space $E_i$ and for any $i$, $j$, $\varphi(U_i\cap U_j)$ is open in $E_i$.
> >
> > **AT 3.** The map
> >     $$
> > \varphi_j\varphi_i^{-1}:\varphi_i(U_i\cap U_j) \rightarrow \varphi_j(U_i\cap U_j)
> > $$
> >     is a $C^p$-isomorphism for each par of indices $i$, $j$.

This definitions is clear. The problem cames in the next claim:

> > It is a trivial exercise in point set topology to prove that one can give $X$ a topology in a unique way such that each $U_i$ is open, and the $\varphi_i$ are topological isomorphisms.

The unique *trivial* way I know to carry such a topology on $X$ is defining $\tau$ as the collection of all $\varphi_i^{-1}A_i$ for every open subset $A_i\subset\varphi_iU_i$ and for every index $i$.

If I would be right, how could I show this topology is unique?

Thanks

Comment: Show first that it is the coarsest topology that makes the $\phi_i$ continuous. This is clear from the construction. But now, if you put more open sets, their images by $\phi_i$ are not open in the corresponding $E_i$. Therefore $\phi_i$ is not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems correct. Basically, this is the [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).

Showing that it is well defined is basically applying the fact that the image of each open set must also be open for these guys to be topological isomorphisms.